# MySql select format, round column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with products that have columns like this: price[decimals 8,5] and decimals [tinyint - max value is 5].
When I list products must show price according to the decimals specified in decimals column.
I tried something like this(with mysql)

```
select p.price, round(p.price, p.decimals) as price, p.decimals
from product p
```

but it returns

```
100.35667   100.35700   3
```

and i would like to be 100.
I also see that 'Round' rounds the number which is not my scope.
Regards.

Comment: This is a bug with `round` function. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29912352/632951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `FORMAT` function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

```
SELECT 
    P.price, 
    FORMAT(P.price, P.decimals) as price, 
    P.decimals
FROM 
    product P;
```

Comment: i tried that even before but it returns error:  [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'P.decimals) as price, 
    P.decimals
FROM 
    product P' at line 3

Comment: here is the create procedure:

Comment: CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fk_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_packaging` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `decimals` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `price` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL,
  `has_special_price` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `special_price_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `added_date` datetime default NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime default NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: syntax is OK, just tested it. which version are you on?

Comment: protocol_version 10
version 5.0.92-community-log
version_comment MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: the `SELECT` is formally correct, please cut&paste it **as is here** and run it. remember that `FORMAT` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: i am having the same issue, however if instead of p.decimals i write 2 then it is running

Comment: @AlexaAdrian, See Rick's answer for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998759/632951