# MySQL Round function is returning too many decimal digits, when the no. of decimal digits are based on a column

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql select format, round column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411656/mysql-select-format-round-column)

When i make a SQL query using the `ROUND(X, D)`, where D is a column name rather than the direct integer value, the result is rounded fine, but has too many decimal digits.

For example,

```
SELECT b.digits, ROUND(a.amount, b.digits) as amount
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.number_id = b.id
```

the result is something like this:

```
3  357.143000000000000000000000
2   89.290000000000000000000000
4  696.436600000000000000000000
2  214.290000000000000000000000
2  328.570000000000000000000000
2  437.500000000000000000000000
```

The column b.digits contains the digits to which the value must be rounded. It is possible to get the result based on the digits, like this:

```
3  357.143
2   89.29
4  696.4366
2  214.29
2  328.57
2  437.50
```

Comment: Works correctly for me, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/048c3/1

Comment: @Barmar: This seems to be trimming the trailing zeros. For example, the last row returns 437.5 instead of 437.50. But in my system, the output shown as i have posted; i am using MySQL version 5.5.12 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with the `format` function:

like this:

`SELECT b.digits, FORMAT(a.amount, b.digits) as amount
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.number_id = b.id`

Comment: This function though returns the result in the format `#,###,###.##`, which is not what is required.