# How to get second argument of Round() to work with columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, if-statement, subquery

I've a simple table with an integer column:

```
# setup table:
create table t(x int); insert t select 1;
```

The query `select round(1.234, 1) from t` returns `1.2` as expected.

However, `select round(1.234, x) from t` returns `1.2000`. (It should return `1.2`, as [per the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).)

Is this a bug?  (Tested on version `5.5.10` and [latest `5.6.24`](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql#files-ga).)

Or, is there any particular *technical* reason why columns cannot be used in the second argument of `round`?

How can we get `round` to work **even while** there are columns used in the second argument?

Comment: mysql does seem to be a bit random about the order in which it evaluates things.  try this: `select if(@z:=sum(5), @z, 'wtf');`

Comment: It works in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22e0e/1.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Doesn't work in official MySQL Community Server. ([mysql-5.6.24-win32.zip, mysql-5.6.24-winx64.zip](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql#files-ga))

Comment: All the three queries working for me tested on
    Server version: 5.6.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: @HardeepPandya, Apologies, serious typo on my part. See the edit.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes some strange behaviour you are right I am getting 1.200 as per your queries. But from my point of view output should be either 1.2 or 1.23
when I run same query with user defined variable it return desired value
SET @i = 0;
SELECT ROUND(1.234, if(@i = 0, 1, 2));

Comment: @HardeepPandya, Exactly what I'm saying. And nice findings you made above, I've added the information from the findings you've found into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) instead of `ROUND`:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(1.234, x) FROM ( SELECT 1 AS x ) y;
+------------------+
| FORMAT(1.234, x) |
+------------------+
| 1.2              |
+------------------+
```

If that is not satisfactory, [file a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com) about `ROUND`.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is not restricted to `ROUND()`, but also happens for `TRUNCATE()`.

The accepted answer/workaround from @RickJames is not entirely correct, since `FORMAT()` introduces thousand separators: [FORMAT() documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Correct workaround for arbitrary values:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(t.raw_number, t.decimal_places), ',', '')
FROM   my_table t;
```

*(Adding my comment as separate answer, since I do not have enough points to comment...)*